# White screen of death but only on log in page?

Tags: configuration

Ive got a copy of a site to work on locally. The instructions were to leave the settings.php how it is and just enter my database details into local_settings.php. Ive done this and the site works fine except except when I try and log in and go to the 'user' page at which point I get the white screen of death.

The site only works the the url doesn't have the https so this is the front page: `http://mysite/`

However when I try and 'user' to the end it redirect to `https://mysite/user` so it adds 's' to the 'http'.

Another quirk that may be relevant is that when I create a brand new site it works fine except that the admin log in doesn't work the first time. I have to use the 'Request new password' link to log in. After that I can log in and out fine.

Comment: try to disable Devel module.

Comment: Its already disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to disable the secure pages module.

Comment: Doesn't sound like proper, safe solution.

Comment: Im sure your right but its sufficient for me to work locally.